# How to init a component with the value of a VueX store field?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I plugged a [`VueX store`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) to a Vue app.

How should I handle the value of fields in a form.

When the form init, it should use the value from the store, but then it shouldn't try to update the value of the immutable state.

Before I was using `v-model` but there I am a bit lost.

I tried something like that:

```
    computed: mapState(["profile"])
    data() {
      return {
        firstname: '',
      };
    },
    created() {
      this.firstname = this.profile.firstname;
    }
```

But then each time I reopen the component, it doesn't update the value from the store.

[`This solution`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/forms.html) is not what I want either, because I want the store to be updated with the value from the server and not the value being currently edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially the state value is empty, try to watch it and update your data object property based on that value :

```
computed: mapState(["profile"]),
watch:{
   profile(val) {
       this.firstname = val.firstname;
   }
  },
   mounted() {
       this.firstname = this.profile.firstname;
   },
```

Comment: It seems that the initial value is not set with this watch.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it:

- On component mount, I set the field value to the component state
- Then I plug v-model to the state and use an action to update the store on submit.

```
<template>
    <div id="login" class="cModal">
        <div>
            <header>
                <h2>Edit Profile</h2>
            </header>
            <div>
                <form @submit="edit()">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <label for="firstname">Firstname</label>
                        <input id="firstname" type="text" v-model="firstname"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <button>Edit profile</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <footer class="cf">
                <a href="#" class="btn" @click="closeModal">Fermer [x]</a>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
  import { mapState } from 'vuex';
  export default {
    computed: mapState(["profile"]),
    data() {
      return {
        firstname: '',
      };
    },
    created() {
      this.firstname = this.profile.firstname;
    },
    methods: {
      edit() {
        this.$emit("handleProfileUpdate", {firstname: this.firstname});
      },
      closeModal() {
        this.$emit("close");
      },
    }
  };
</script>
```